# ActionBar Not Displaying When Using Custom Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When I use the following code, the actionbar will not display in my app:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/fb_dark_blue</item>
</style>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Make sure you're using a theme in the Theme.AppCompat family [as described in the android documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html#Theme_AppCompat)
2. When creating a project in eclipse, the wizard will create multiple values folders for different api levels.  This has screwed me up in the past.  See if you have other values directories, such as values-v11 or values-v14.  These may contain what your app is actually reading from.

Comment: I can't seem to get the AppCompat library to work. I'll look around a little more.